# PHP: MYSQLI Change Order By Style

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

[image]

Hi, i want to get data from `chat` table like this:

```
6
7
8
```

My Code show like this:

```
8
7
6
```

Code:

```
"SELECT * FROM `chat` WHERE 
    `chat-code` = 'vm1mxo3dpi9gzuo' AND (`user_1` = '1' OR `user_2` = '1') 
     ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3"
```

Comment: change `DESC` with `ASC` thats it.

Comment: @KunalAwasthi No, WITH ASC i get 1,2,3 i want 6,7,8

Comment: Your deleted answer is the correct approach

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `chat`
WHERE `chat-code` = 'vm1mxo3dpi9gzuo'
AND (`user_1` = '1' OR `user_2` = '1')
ORDER BY id LIMIT 3 OFFSET 5
```

Try above query.

Comment: I Get 1,2,3 i Want 6,7,8

Comment: @GAASD Then you have to go with `OFFSET`

Comment: @SagarGangwal But with this offset, it will only work as long as there are only 5 messages in front of the messages he want to select. As soon as there is another message, the offset should increment...

Answer (score 0):

Because you're ordering your result in descending order. You should remove the **desc** in ORDER BY. You can explicitly put ASC to indicate the order as ascending.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change your query to this (order by text ASC):

```
SELECT * FROM `chat`
WHERE `chat-code` = 'vm1mxo3dpi9gzuo' AND
(`user_1` = '1' OR `user_2` = '1')
ORDER BY text ASC LIMIT 3
```

If you still want to order by ID, simply change the DESC to ASC

Comment: I Get 1,2,3 i Want 6,7,8

Answer (score 0):

Try to read what will happens if you use DESC or ASC statements. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sorting-rows.html 
Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

use this mat and you can change the between parameters with prepared statements.comment if doesn't work.

```
"SELECT * FROM `chat` WHERE `chat-code` = 'vm1mxo3dpi9gzuo'
AND (`user_1`='1' OR `user_2` = '1') 
AND `id` between 6 and 10  //starting and ending offset for query so query doesn't take long time
ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 3" // LIMIT 3 as you mentioned and ASC order
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution of your problem - use below query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM `chat`
    WHERE `chat-code` = 'vm1mxo3dpi9gzuo' AND
    (`user_1` = '1' OR `user_2` = '1')
    ORDER BY `text` DESC LIMIT 3
) t ORDER BY `text` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.*
  FROM 
     ( SELECT * 
         FROM chat 
        WHERE `chat-code` = 'vm1mxo3dpi9gzuo' 
          AND 1 IN(user_1,user_2) 
        ORDER 
           BY id DESC 
        LIMIT 3
     ) a
 ORDER 
    BY id;
```

Comment: an explanation as to why that would work helps everyone.

Comment: @jwenting Amongst those that might be interested in this kind of thing, I think it's self explanatory